# Given a nonempty bounded subset $A$ of reals, show that there are equivalent Cauchy sequences

Tags: real-analysis

Sorry the title is not long enough to fit the question.

But given such a set $A$, how do I show that there are equivalent Cauchy sequences say $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ such that every $a_n$ is an upper bound for $A$ and no $b_n$ is an upper bound for $A$? Is this related to the proof that Cauchy sequences are bounded? The equivalent part is confusing, how can they be equivalent and have different limits?

Comment: As an example, choose $A = (-2, 0).$ Set $a_n=\frac{1}{n}, b_n=-\frac{1}{n}.$ I think this example will clear your confusion.

Comment: @Krish I see thank you! so $a_n$ and $b_n$ are equivalent Cauchy sequences? do you know how to prove the problem?

Comment: How do you define equivalent Cauchy sequences?

Comment: if $a_n$ and $b_n$ are equivalent the sequence $\{a_n -b_n\} =0$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Given $A$ is bounded, so the supremum exists. Let $a$ be the supremum of $A.$ For each $n \in \mathbb N,$ choose $a_n=a+\frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n =a-\frac{1}{n}.$

*Added:* First assume that $a \in A.$ Then clearly $b_n$ is not an upper bound of $A,$ for any $n \in \mathbb N.$ Now suppose $a \notin A.$ Since $a$ is the supremum, for any $n \in \mathbb N,$ there is a $x_n \in A$ such that $b_n=a - \frac{1}{n} < x_n.$

Comment: I don't see how every $b_n$ is not an upper bound, please explain?

Comment: @grayQuant: I've added an explanation. See if it's fine.